# Trouble after installing Watson Studio Desktop from the Windows 10 64 bits

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-studio

The program does not respond from the project creation right after installation. (ID verification is complete) I deleted it several times and tried to install it again, but it is not solved at all and updating all programs of my computer such as Java, R is not solved. Is there anyone who is experiencing the same phenomenon as me?

Answer (score -1):

Most install problems are a result of a incomplete or corrupt download. Try re-downloading the latest version of WSD and see if it resolves the issue.